# Optimising runtime for lists in Python

Tags: python, list, performance, time-complexity

I am trying to optimise the runtime for my python program.

I am working with an ordered list, which I need to update every loop by removing an item and adding an item, and the new item needs to be placed in the correct location so the list remains ordered. Also, the items are integers.

I know that generally the run time is O(n) for adding and removing from a list in python, but I wonder is there any faster methods for ordered lists?

Comment: Did you check if https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity helps you decide?

Comment: No. The only time you can get good performance from adding/removing form a list is by adding/removing from end.

Comment: @usr2564301 thank you, yes I have seen this page but it doesn't seem to talk about the particular case of ordered lists

Comment: @tam63 However, [the Sorted Containers library](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) would be worth checking out.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you, this looks promising